# How to implement RPN in Faster RCNN for object detection?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, faster-rcnn

I am trying to implement the Faster RCNN on identifying the airplane from the image. I stuck at implementing Region Proposal Network(RPN). How can I implement RPN and train them to produce bounding box proposal using python script?

Comment: Are you sure you want to re-implement it rather than using a `torchvision` model (or the `Keras` equivalent) like this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html#finetuning-from-a-pretrained-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ready-to-use implementations of various neural networks including Faster RCNN. Consider using DL frameworks such as Pytorch or Keras.
For example, see [this Pytorch tutorial on fine-tuning the Mask R-CNN model](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html).

Faster RCNN is a two-stage object detection model. Where the first stage is an RPN (Region Proposal Network), and the second is a classifier. For your task, you can ignore the second part if you don't need it.

Some implementations:

[Faster RCNN in Pytorch](https://github.com/jwyang/faster-rcnn.pytorch)

[Faster RCNN in Keras](https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN)